# Label attribute table column

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I simply want to label a column in the attributes table as: "line 1", "line 2", "line 3" etc. I am sure there's an easy fix but couldn't find the exact solution from other posts.

(using QGIS 2.18.7)

Each row represents a different line feature (GPS track)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the simpelst form I can think of is:

- Open field calculator and update the field with:

  ```
  concat( 'line ',  $id)
  ```
- the result would be "line 1", "line 2" and so on
- if you **need** to start at 1 use:

  ```
  concat( 'line ',  $id +1)
  ```

Comment: This is almost there, but it starts at "line 0" any way to make it start at "line 1"?

Comment: @Joseph added your input :)

Comment: perfect, solved :)